# How to replace value in text file with integer? - Groovy (Qupath)

Tags: groovy, replace, config

I want to replace a specific value with an integer in a text value. Seems like I am missing something important.

```
x=5


def file = new File('/Users/path/name.txt')
def newConfig = file.text.replace('abc',x)
file.text = newConfig
```

tried `x.toString()` but did not help either.

**I am using this code to generate a number, and need that number to be replaced within a .json file.**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a file with the following string:

```
testabcandanotherabc
abcandabcandanotherabc
```

I use the following code:

```
x = 5
def file = new File('/Users/path/name.txt')
def newConfig = file.text.replaceAll('abc', x.toString())
file.write(newConfig)
```

It changes the file content as following:

```
test5andanother5
5and5andanother5
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked great! If you have any helpful information on coding in Groovy, that would also be much appreciated.